# Is there some tool that allows users to see trends with questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Just wondering whether it would be useful to have a tool similar to [Google Trends](http://www.google.com.au/trends/) that allows the users to see the questions and answers that are trending. I think it is a useful gauge of the technology and problems that people are having issue with, and gives new users a good overview of where they can start participating.

Comment: Are you looking for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer? This information could be retrieved using that

Comment: Take a look at http://data.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I have used this previously, but does it allow you to create a plot that shows the trend over time?

Comment: You mean something like http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/166577/percentage-of-accepted-answers-over-time-by-month#graph ? (Link goes to a query a while back that I made in response to something that came up on Meta Mathematics)

Comment: @DennisMeng That's right, something like that but always showing so we don't have to run queries and get the graphs for things that will provide a good indication of the metrics that reflect the trends of UX design on UX StackExchange.